# Please give me a html/css pattern with sticky header and footer and STICKY content

Tags: jquery, html, css

It is easy to implement a one-page html with a sticky header, sticky footer and scrollable content.

But I divided my content into two parts. The left part is a menu(or a nav bar), and I want it to be scrollable.

like

```
header
---------------------
       |
       |
 scrol | other
 lable | content
       |
       |
---------------------
footer
```

html like

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="left"></div>
        <div class="right"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

I don't know how to make the .left to be scrollable.

What I have tried:

```
.box {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
}
.content {
    flex-grow: 1;
    /*overflow: auto;*/
}
.left {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

If I add `overflow: auto;` to `.content`, the scroll bar scrolls the whole content div.

If I add `overflow: auto;` to `.content`, the scroll bar doesn't appear on `.left` div, and 100% height even doesn't work too. The scroll bar appears on the whole html.

I have tried a solution, but in that solution I must know the height of header and footer. I want a pattern with flexibility.

I have read several answers about 'take remaining place', etc, but hadn't get an answer, so I ask here. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this answer will help...

```css
html,
body{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.header,
.footer{
  height: 50px;
  background: yellow;
}
.box {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
}
.content {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: 100%;
}
.left {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 120px;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
    color: #fff;
}
right{
    width: calc(100% - 120px);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <div class="header">Header</div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="left"> Left Content Left Content Left Content Left Content Left Content Left Content Left Content Left Content Left Content Left Content Left Content Left Content Left Content Left Content Left Content Left Content Left Content Left Content Left Content Left Content </div>
        <div class="right"> Right Content </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body{        
        padding-top: 60px;
        padding-bottom: 40px;
    }
    .container{
        width: 80%;
        margin: 0 auto; /* Center the DIV horizontally */
    }
    .header, .footer{
        width: 100%;
        position: fixed;        
        background: #333;
        padding: 10px 0;
        color: #fff;
    }
    .header{
        top: 0;
    }
    .footer{
        bottom: 0;
    }    
    /* Some more styles to beutify this example */
    
     p{
        line-height: 200px; /* Create scrollbar to test positioning */
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Creating Fixed Header and Footer with CSS</title>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        header
    </div>
    <div class="container">
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam eu sem tempor, varius quam at, luctus dui. Mauris magna metus, dapibus nec turpis vel, semper malesuada ante. Vestibulum id metus ac nisl bibendum scelerisque non non purus. Suspendisse varius nibh non aliquet sagittis. In tincidunt orci sit amet elementum vestibulum. Vivamus fermentum in arcu in aliquam. Quisque aliquam porta odio in fringilla. Vivamus nisl leo, blandit at bibendum eu, tristique eget risus. Integer aliquet quam ut elit suscipit, id interdum neque porttitor. Integer faucibus ligula.</p>
        <p>Quis quam ut magna consequat faucibus. Pellentesque eget nisi a mi suscipit tincidunt. Ut tempus dictum risus. Pellentesque viverra sagittis quam at mattis. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam sit amet gravida nibh, facilisis gravida odio. Phasellus auctor velit at lacus blandit, commodo iaculis justo viverra. Etiam vitae est arcu. Mauris vel congue dolor. Aliquam eget mi mi. Fusce quam tortor, commodo ac dui quis, bibendum viverra erat. Maecenas mattis lectus enim, quis tincidunt dui molestie euismod. Curabitur et diam tristique, accumsan nunc eu, hendrerit tellus.</p>
    </div>    
    <div class="footer">
        Copyright &copy; 2016 Your Company      
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.content{
            display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        }
        .header, .footer{
            width: 100%;
            position: fixed;        
            background: #333;
            padding: 10px 0;
            color: #fff;
        }
        .header{
            top: 0;
        }
        .footer{
            bottom: 0;
        }  
        .left,.right{width: 50%;
        }
        .left{
          height: 200px; overflow-y:auto;
        }
        
         p{
            line-height: normal; 
        }
```

```html
    <div class="header">
            header
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="left">
              <ul>
                <li>test1</li>
                <li>test2</li>
                <li>test3</li>
                <li>test4</li>
                <li>test5</li>
                <li>test6</li>
                <li>test7</li>
                <li>test8</li>
                 <li>test1</li>
                <li>test2</li>
                <li>test3</li>
                <li>test4</li>
                <li>test5</li>
                <li>test6</li>
                <li>test7</li>
                <li>test8</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="right">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam eu sem tempor, varius quam at, luctus dui. Mauris magna metus, dapibus nec turpis vel, semper malesuada ante. Vestibulum id metus ac nisl bibendum scelerisque non non purus. Suspendisse varius nibh non aliquet sagittis. In tincidunt orci sit amet elementum vestibulum. Vivamus fermentum in arcu in aliquam. Quisque aliquam porta odio in fringilla. Vivamus nisl leo, blandit at bibendum eu, tristique eget risus. Integer aliquet quam ut elit suscipit, id interdum neque porttitor. Integer faucibus ligula.</p>
            
            </div>
        </div> 
        <div class="footer">
            Copyright &copy; 2016 Your Company      
        </div>
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution where `.content` is a flexbox row and has `overflow: hidden`, while `.left` has `overflow: auto`

```css
html,
body,
.box {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  background: silver;
}

.content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.header {
  background: tomato;
}

.footer {
  background: teal;
}

.left {
  background: lime;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.right {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: navy;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="header">
    <h1>.header</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="left">
      <ul>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>

      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <p>
        .right
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <h6>.footer</h6>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering me such a simple question. But, if I add `height` to  `header` and `footer`, then copy <li> elements, double the count, I will find the height of header/footer is different. Why?